# Use re to detect string with any numbers, symbols, or letters

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a python program and am trying to do a `re.search` to find a specific pattern in text. The issue I am facing is that the middle search for `"[a-zA-Z0-9/" ]+"` does not find any number/symbol/or letter and I have to specify each type of symbol I want it to pick up on.

```
re.search(r'[0-9] [a-zA-Z0-9/" ]+ [0-9]', text)
```

I am trying to detect strings in text.

Comment: Have you experimented on a [Regex testing](https://regex101.com) site?

Comment: Show us some sample text that you want this pattern to match.  Otherwise we are just guessing what you actually want.

Comment: An example text would be this: X 2989 HELLO WORLD@*$# 299 E

Comment: Why would you expect that text to match?  The pattern is a digit, followed by a space, followed by one or more letters, digits, slashes, double-quotes or spaces, followed by a space, followed by a digit.  The text you gave does not match that pattern.  The part `9 HELLO WORLD@*$# 2` comes somewhat close, but the `@*$#` makes it not match.

Comment: Can you say _specifically_ why you expected that text to match?

Comment: I didn't expect that text to match with my current program, but would like to modify the middle of the re.search program  (this [a-zA-Z0-9/" ]+ )   so it does match without specifically specifying that I would like to allow "@" "*" "$" and "#" in the program.

Comment: I used an extreme example so I can ensure my program will work on all variations of the text provided.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for non space, so each time you may not specify each time of symbol in the character class.
x = re.search(r'[0-9] \S+ [0-9]', text)

Samples are provided in the below link. Try this, if it helps you.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response! The middle item can have spaces in it.

Comment: Is it possible to make it allow all characters including spaces?

Comment: Could you please help with the sample input and expected output.